# TypeError: TradingApp.error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'advancedOrderRejectJson'

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, interactive-brokers

I am using Python 3.1, Spyder 5.4.2, and IB API 10.19

`

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time


class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)
        
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson):
        print("Error {} {} {} {}".format(reqId,errorCode,errorString,advancedOrderRejectJson))
        
    def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        print("redID: {}, contract:{}".format(reqId,contractDetails))

def websocket_con():
    app.run()
    event.wait()
    #if event.is_set():
        #app.close()

event = threading.Event()   
app = TradingApp()      
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 4001, clientId=1)

# starting a separate daemon thread to execute the websocket connection
con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con)
con_thread.start()
time.sleep(1) # some latency added to ensure that the connection is established

#creating object of the Contract class - will be used as a parameter for other function calls
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "AAPL"
contract.secType = "STK"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.exchange = "SMART"

app.reqContractDetails(100, contract) # EClient function to request contract details
time.sleep(5) # some latency added to ensure that the contract details request has been processed
event.set()
```

I can run this successfully once in the IDE, a second time it fails with the mentioned error. If I close the IPython Console I can run it again, a second time if fails. If I open the terminal and navigate to the dir and run it will not run at all and fails with the above-mentioned error

I have tried commenting out the error function with similar results. It runs only after closing the IPython Console tab, and does not run at all in the console, giving `AttributeError: 'TradingApp' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As it is given, the amount of code isn't enough as there is no clear indication of what is being run.  What is ```app```?  What is ```event```?  Please include the full traceback error.    How are you running this app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have tried running in the Spyder IDE and it works one time, then I have to kill the IPython tab before it will run again. I also tried running in terminal in dir in which it is in and it will not run at all.

Comment: What is the full traceback? Because it sounds like the error message is received in the old format. Make sure your TWS/Gateway are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

advancedOrderRejectJson is not always passed by IB, and if you are overriding it in your subclass, then provide a default empty string value to handle this:

```
def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson=''):
        print("Error {} {} {} {}".format(reqId,errorCode,errorString,advancedOrderRejectJson))
```